# Moving a geometry using PyQGIS3

Tags: python, pyqgis-3, qgis-3

I have a layer which has one feature. I try to move the feature(multipolygon) using the script below:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    prev_pos = feat.geometry().centroid().asPoint()
    success  = feat.geometry().translate(100, 100) # translation
    next_pos = feat.geometry().centroid().asPoint()

    print(success)        
    print(prev_pos)
    print(next_pos)
```

But I get different results in QGIS 2 and QGIS 3. (The multipolygon has many points, therefore, I printed out only its centroid)

Output in QGIS 2:

```
0 # means operation succeeded
(552084,433685)
(552184,433785) # changed coordinates
```

Output in QGIS 3:

```
0 # means operation succeeded
<QgsPointXY: POINT(552084 433685)>
<QgsPointXY: POINT(552084 433685)> # same coordinates
```

When I try to move a point feature, I get same results.

Why does not `translate` method move the feature in QGIS 3? What am I missing?

---

**EDIT:** If I create a `QgsGeometry`  object manually, `translate` method works correctly in QGIS 3.

```
points = [QgsPointXY(0,0), QgsPointXY(2,0), QgsPointXY(2,2), QgsPointXY(0,2)]
geom = QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolygonXY( [ [points] ] )
print(geom)

geom.translate(100, 100)
print(geom)
```

Output in QGIS 3:

```
<QgsGeometry: MultiPolygon (((0 0, 2 0, 2 2, 0 2, 0 0)))>
<QgsGeometry: MultiPolygon (((100 100, 102 100, 102 102, 100 102, 100 100)))>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To change `QgsFeature` geometry in QGIS 3 you have to call `setGeometry()` explicitly.

```
geom = feat.geometry()
geom.translate(100, 100)
feat.setGeometry(geom)
```

Explanation:

In QGIS 2 `geometry()` returns a pointer, so it can be modified in place.

```
QgsGeometry* QgsFeature::geometry() //QGIS 2
```

In QGIS 3 `geometry()` returns value instead of a pointer. Additionally it is const now, so it is not allowed to modify the `QgsFeature`.

```
QgsGeometry QgsFeature::geometry() const //QGIS 3
```

(see https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsFeature.html#ab0a934a1b173ce5ad8d13363c20ef3c8)

Answer (score 6):

In your examples the manipulated geometry is not written back to data source.
The [Python Cookbook for PyQGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#modify-features) offers two possibilities:

(1) using te methods `changeAttributeValues()`, `changeGeometryValues()` of the `dataProvider`
(2) do that within an editing buffer, to have the possibility to explicte save in an commit and so on.

a solution for (1) based on your script:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = feat.geometry()
    print(geom.asWkt())
    success  = geom.translate(100, 100) # translation

    fid = feat.id()
    print('id:',fid)
    layer.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues({ fid : geom })

# reread geoms to see if they changed
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = feat.geometry()
    print(geom.asWkt())
```

Comment: To write back to data source is next step. The problem is that the geometry (in memory) is not translated in QGIS 3.0 using `translate` method. But, yes, your suggestion is a part of solution. Using a variable (`geom`) for `feat.geometry()` is reasonable. As @bartekschas pointed out in his/her answer, while `geometry()` returns a pointer in QGIS 2, it doesn't return a pointer in QGIS 3. The problem is related to that.

Comment: I don't see the problem, I suppose it's the way it's meant to be. What are you trying to achieve with your code?